# facebook share box not showing title, description and images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

http://gates.cc/works/thisisyours/site/p/fairytale-fashion-collection-61 this is my website url. Here you can see the facebook share using addthis on right side. Please help me what problem in this page. In facebook share box have link only not showing the title, description and the images.

Comment: Hi, I test with custom share using three images in array still it showing single image only please help me to fix. See the link http://gates.cc/works/guna/testfb.php.

Comment: Well I get everything proper, http://postimg.org/image/3w8da56hr/

Also Facebook debugger displays no errors for your URl https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgates.cc%2Fworks%2Fthisisyours%2Fsite%2Fp%2Ffairytale-fashion-collection-61

You've set only one image in og:image tag and it is displayed properly

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :**

Facebook treats each url as unique and caches the page based on that url, so if you want to share the latest url the simplest solution is to add a query string with the url being shared. In simple words just add ?v=1 at the end of the url. Any number can be used in place of 1.

**Method 2:**

Facebook has a tool called [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (formerly known as URL Linter). This tool gives us an idea about how a url will be shared on Facebook, what content, which image will be fetched.

I hope this helps